# What could possibly set Windows To Go certified USB drives apart from uncertified ones?

Tags: windows-8, windows-to-go

Since the choice between "Windows To Go"-certified drives is so limited ([Microsoft - Windows To Go](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/devices/windowstogo.aspx#deviceListHeader)) and so expensive - I wondered if there could be anything as simple as a flag on the USB or just identification via the device descriptors (which could be faked/altered?).

I imagine it's not something that is straight-forward since solutions are not present this day and "certification" must have some sort of protection to stay in place.

Did anyone even have promising results with uncertified USB 3.0 SSDs attached ? I've only seen msdn blogs along with the official WinToUSB source literally tell people to not waste their time on uncertified devices.

What is your thoughts on this ?

In my opinion Windows To Go and it's usefulness is rather crippled since it's overly expensive and restricted for some reason. Compared to the thriving Linux LiveCD community it seems a rather puny attempt.

Comment: They run at some specified speed that's about it; Mjcrosoft evens says that on the page you linked too

Comment: Yes. But how come non-certified USB's with decent high random writes also perform so bad that people wouldn't even dare to recommend trying it ?

Answer (score -1):

Windows ability to consistently identify removable drives of any sort is quite pathetic. (i.e.: it's not your fault that it's broken)

Consider installing USBDLM (http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html). It's free and actually quite well engineered.

Comment: This is about the "certified" Windows-To-Go removable drives however and not USB/Windows in general.

Comment: Please educate me. If, in fact, a manufacturer pays a fee, then Windows auto-mount of drives will become configurable? I suppose if the fees are reasonable, I'd go along with it. Is there a list? Our scenario is backing up to a separate removable drive nightly and having a sequence of 6 moved off-site. They all need to mount on the same path so the backup will run. Bare Windows is horribly inconsistent in its ability to do this; so we resorted to USBDLM to guarantee some degree of mount-point predictability (i.e. which letter is assigned). [lame] [sigh]

Comment: What does it have to do with the Windows-To-Go speed/performance and the inability to use reasonable performance USB3.0 pens in place of the certified ones? Sorry - I still find your comments insightful, but I fail to see what it has to do with the original question ?